# Who gives the Oyster.com review score?

Tags: online-resources, hotels, reviews

When I look at a hotel at Oyster.com, there is a score (on a 0 to 5 scale) provided for the hotel. For example, [the Plaza Hotel](https://www.oyster.com/new-york-city/hotels/the-plaza/) was given 5 out of 5.

Is this score based on user reviews, or a single score provided by the one oyster reviewer who reviewed that hotel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The score is given by the Oyster reviewer.

This seems to be the concept of the website:

> Oyster is the only hotel site that sends special investigators to visit, photograph, review, and rate each hotel. We inspect in-person — just like your mother-in-law.

On [their page about their so-called investigators](https://www.oyster.com/about/investigators/), they say about their rating:

> We Rate Hotels Fairly
>
> Though our reviews are unabashedly honest, we are careful to evaluate each hotel within the context of its category.